# How can I render a bloom coming from an object off screen

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render the bloom coming from an object off-screen in Eevee but having difficulty. Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the *Render panel > Film*, enable the *Overscan* value in order to take into account what's off camera view, you can type a value over 10% if needed:

[image]